# GPS calculations in Java

Tags: java, api, gps

I'm looking for a java API, **a free one**, that provides basic functionality for calculating distances between GPS coordinates. I need the basic getDistance between two points, Points of Interest in a radius around a point.
I've done a bit of research and found on the one hand some options.

On the one hand there is Apache SIS (http://incubator.apache.org/sis/index.html) but this is still under development and might change some.
On the other there is GeoTools (http://docs.geotools.org/), but this is rather complex for my needs.

Are there any other easy to use and simpler APIs out there?

One other option would be to simply implement all this myself, I've seen some examples of own implementations, but all of them have some comments of the sort: "this doesn't realy work, it provides a distance that is off by 100 meters". How reliable would such an implementation be?

Comment: Do you need the roads being taken into account ? Or just the straight distance ?

Comment: Just the distance between two points. Most common use case would be, give me the people within 10 meters of this point.

Comment: I *think* I've got a code fragment somewhere how to do this with GeoTools. The api - at that time - was awful, but I managed to do that. However, if everything is on the scale of meters, I think you can safely revert to Cartesian math - convert to degrees and use A²=B²+C².

Comment: Thanks for the comments, but no, not everything is on the scale of meters unfortunatelly. It might even be hundreds of kilometers...

Comment: I don't have the fragment at hand - but a quick search shows me what you might be looking for is: http://docs.geotools.org/latest/javadocs/org/geotools/referencing/GeodeticCalculator.html

Comment: Yup, that's what I came across. Only downside of geotools from my point of view is that it's a lot more than I need. Other than that, it's the best option so far.

Comment: It seems it's not too bad with Geotools. I've posted an answer. Hope this is what you need.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using GeoTools and Maven, it should not be too difficult. Maven will take care of the dependencies. And luckily you won't need the whole Geotools suite to do the "headless" calculations.

I hope it's what you're looking for.

The pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.bar</groupId>
  <artifactId>geo</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>maven2-repository.dev.java.net</id>
      <name>Java.net repository</name>
      <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <id>osgeo</id>
      <name>Open Source Geospatial Foundation Repository</name>
      <url>http://download.osgeo.org/webdav/geotools/</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
      <snapshots>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
      </snapshots>
      <id>opengeo</id>
      <name>OpenGeo Maven Repository</name>
      <url>http://repo.opengeo.org</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.geotools</groupId>
      <artifactId>gt-referencing</artifactId>
      <version>9.0</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

The code:

```
package org.bar;

import org.geotools.referencing.GeodeticCalculator;
import java.awt.geom.Point2D;

/**
 * How far is NY from London ?
 */
public class DistanceTest {

  public final static void main(final String[] args) {
    final GeodeticCalculator calc = new GeodeticCalculator();

    final Point2D london = new Point2D.Double(-0.127512, 51.507222);
    final Point2D ny = new Point2D.Double(-73.94, 40.67 );
    calc.setStartingGeographicPoint(london);
    calc.setDestinationGeographicPoint(ny);

    System.out.println("Distance London-NY: " + calc.getOrthodromicDistance()/1000 + " kms");
  }

}
```

Comment: Looks a lot like what I need. Main point you make is that I don't need the whole Geotools set.

Comment: This is of course the easy solution: No elevation. There's a referencing 3d module in GeoTools, but I don't know whether that would take elevation into account.

Comment: This would make it work for me with gradle (the repo above does not seem to work anymore):

    repositories {
        maven { url "https://repo.osgeo.org/repository/release/" }
    }
    
    dependencies {
          implementation "org.geotools:gt-referencing:23.0"
    }

Answer (score 1):

Did you try http://www.dinopolis.org/gpsylon/.
I provides features like :

- Measure distance.
- Location marker

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Geocalc](https://github.com/grumlimited/geocalc)

```
//Kew
Coordinate lat = new DegreeCoordinate(51.4843774);
Coordinate lng = new DegreeCoordinate(-0.2912044);
Point kew = new Point(lat, lng);

//Richmond, London
lat = new DegreeCoordinate(51.4613418);
lng = new DegreeCoordinate(-0.3035466);
Point richmond = new Point(lat, lng);

double distance = EarthCalc.getVincentyDistance(richmond, kew); //in meters
double bearing = EarthCalc.getVincentyBearing(kew, richmond); //in decimal degrees
```

Answer (score 0):

OpenStreetMaps (http://www.openstreetmap.us/) have some pretty helpful free and simple to use APIs.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a collection of location-oriented APIs that you'll probably find useful:

https://www.temboo.com/library/keyword/location/

Based on your question, the best fit is Google Distance Matrix API. The API documentation is here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distancematrix/

Answer (score -1):

I favour [Geodesy](https://github.com/ndimiduk/geodesy).

It's made up of only 7 classes. So it's totally easy to use.